# Reload page only once

Tags: javascript

How can I reload my page only once adding to this code:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $("#ReloadPage").load(location.href+" #ReloadPage>*","");
}, 500); // seconds to wait, miliseconds
```

The code is set to reload the page every time. How can I reload my page only once?

Comment: Use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `setInterval` with `setTimeout`.